# Django Channels - connected isn't executed

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am copying parts of the GitHub project multichat from the creator of Django channels.

I am making slight changes to the code like not using jQuery, renaming of some consumers and such.

I have literally no errors when running the code however when I join the page and the JS creates a websocket it says simply

```
[2017/08/03 13:13:48] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /chat/stream [127.0.0.1:37070]
[2017/08/03 13:13:48] WebSocket CONNECT /chat/stream [127.0.0.1:37070]
```

Which one would think is fine of course... However in my connect function I have a print("********CONNECTED**********"), which is nowhere to be seen in the console. It simply doesn't run the function I have told it to when someone connects, but it still says the person connected and it throws no errors.

This is the main routing:

```
channel_routing = [
    include("crypto_chat.routing.websocket_routing", path=r"^/chat-stream/$"),
        include("crypto_chat.routing.chat_routing"),
]
```

Routing from app:

```
websocket_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]

chat_routing = [
    route("chat.receive", chat_send, command="^send$"),
    route("chat.receive", user_online, command="^online$"),
```

Connect Consumer:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    # only accept connection if you have any rooms to join
    print("******************CONNECT*************************''")
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # init rooms - add user to the groups and pk num to the session
    message.channel_session['rooms'] = []
    for room in Room.objects.get(users=message.user):
        room.websocket_group.add(message.reply_channel)
        message.channel_session['rooms'].append(room.pk)

    print(message.channel_session['rooms'])
```

Here's JS (note: I am using the JS extension that is available on the project website also):

```
function send_msg(){
    var msg=document.getElementById('msg_input').value;
    console.log("sending msg" + msg);

    webSocketBridge.send({
                "command": "send",
                "room": "1",
                "message": msg
            });
}
    // logging
    var ws_path = "/chat/stream";
    console.log("connecting to " + ws_path);
    // connect
    var webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
    webSocketBridge.connect(ws_path);
    // listen loop
    webSocketBridge.listen(function(data)
    {
        // read json file and act accordingly
        if(data.error){
            // post error message in chat
            console.log("Error - " + data.error);
            return;
        }
        // handle if the user comes back online
        if(data.online){
            console.log("User is online");
        }
        else if(data.offline){
            console.log("User offline");
        }
        else if(data.message){
            console.log("Got message");
        }
        else{  console.log("Unknown message type");  }
    });

    // Helpful debugging
webSocketBridge.socket.onopen = function () {
    console.log("Connected to chat socket");
};
webSocketBridge.socket.onclose = function () {
    console.log("Disconnected from chat socket");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websocket paths should match on server and client side. On server side, you have `/chat-stream/` and on client side `/chat/stream`. These should match. Also, make sure you don't forget the trailing slash as [django explicitly requires it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#definitive-urls).

Comment: Yah thanks i noticed some time ago :p, but +1 for seeing that :)

Comment: @Bolian: you are always welcome to answer your own questions if you find the answer, might help someone having the same issue...